# Python - How do I write an array to a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, file, text

I have two arrays that are being generated from web scraping every minute. There are two of them below. How do I put them in a text file? I want each array to take up one line and I want them to keep their brackets and commas. I haven't found much help with other topics about this.

```
[('76,433', '15.025'), ('99,714', '15.023'), ('44,236', '15.010'), ('718,725', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000')]

[('18,622', '15.027'), ('334', '15.029'), ('3,240', '15.032'), ('11,354', '15.032'), ('13,651', '15.033'), ('96', '15.041'), ('1,997', '15.051'), ('1,760', '15.051'), ('500', '15.052'), ('16,000', '15.053'), ('272', '15.091'), ('3,834', '15.097'), ('8', '15.125'), ('634', '15.141'), ('794', '15.143'), ('528', '15.149'), ('220', '15.150'), ('94', '15.159'), ('91', '15.164')]
```

Comment: Why does it matter that they're arrays?  You can string-ify them and write them to a text file like any other text.

Comment: They're going to be accessed by another server running Rbx.Lua so I want them to be organized so its easier for the other server to use the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you want the file to be used by a Rbx.Lua script, you might be better off using JSON.

`repr` may produce a single line, but you will need to parse it yourself in Lua. Perhaps not too difficult, but if you ever want to exchange other data types you will need to modify your Lua code. You might also find that `repr` does not always give you something useful.

Using JSON is easy:

Python:

```
import json

l = [('76,433', '15.025'), ('99,714', '15.023'), ('44,236', '15.010'), ('718,725', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000')]

with open('l.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(l, outfile)
```

---

```
$ cat l.json
[["76,433", "15.025"], ["99,714", "15.023"], ["44,236", "15.010"], ["718,725", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["60", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["60", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"], ["15", "15.000"], ["30", "15.000"]]
```

See http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=JSON for the Rbx.Lua end; you would use `DecodeJSON()` to convert to a Lua table.

Comment: a newline (`'\n'`) can't be inside a json string, therefore you can always write a json document as a single line (a newline will be escaped: `r'\n'`). Though you should be careful with Unicode newlines such as (`'\u2028'`) if you use `ensure_ascii=False` (the default is `ensure_ascii=True` so that it is represented as `r'\u2028'` and there is no issue). btw, to write to a file, you could pass the object directly: `json.dump(l, outfile)` instead of creating an intermediary string.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: thanks for that... I had forgotten about `dump()`.

Comment: @mhawke: Thanks for the help. I will use JSON tomorrow (It's 11:40pm right now). In the meantime, I'm running my program for 24 hours and recording every minute so I know when the general highs and lows for the rates are. I will also try `dump()` and will set your answer as the best answer if I can get it to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `repr` function like this, it will keep the array structure intact:

```
v = [('76,433', '15.025'), ('99,714', '15.023'), ('44,236', '15.010'), ('718,725', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('60', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000'), ('15', '15.000'), ('30', '15.000')]
f.write(repr(v))
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr).

Comment: Thanks, repr kept everything and put it in one line.

Comment: @GShocked: instead of `repr()`, you could [use a more portable `json` format here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28653612/4279).

Answer (score 0):

you can convert them to str, then write to file:
    Demo:

```
f = open('your_file', 'w')
a = ['1', '2', '3']
f.write(str(a)+"\n")
```

while reading back you can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
f = open("your_file")
for x in f:
    x = ast.literal_eval(x.strip())
    # now do your stuff
```

Comment: I want them to keep their brackets & commas though. I also need them to be in one line. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @GShocked  nothing will be lost give it a try